# How to label more that 7 classes with featurePlot?

Tags: r, plot, r-caret

I have plotted some train data with the following command

```
obj<-featurePlot(x=otto.all[,1:5], y = otto.all$target, plot="pairs", auto.key = list(columns = 9))
```

data contains 9 classes in `target`. Unfortunately, I found, that function 
had repeated colors for last two classes:

[image]

**UPDATE**

The following code

```
obj<-featurePlot(x=otto.all[,1:5], y = otto.all$target, plot="pairs", auto.key = list(columns = 9),col=c("#d82b25","#073ca5","#9c9ea0","#ffce49","#03f92c","#16f4c2","#69167e","#191a92","#000000"))
```

apparently affects individual plots, but not the legend:

[image]

As you see, cyan presents in plot, but absent in legend. Also legent still repeats last two colors.

(last two colors are blue and magenta as first two)

How to make it either not repeat automatically, or assign specific colors explicitly?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the superpose.symbol graphical parameter does the trick.
To see your current theme use `show.settings()`; to see the current values for superpose.symbol use `str(trellis.par.get("superpose.symbol"))`.  These are the values we need to change.

So, lets come up with a set of colors, say

`myColors<- c("#000000", "#7fff00", "#8b0000", "#9932cc", "#ff7f00", "#458b00", "#008b8b", "#0000ff", "#ffff00" )`

and nine different symbols too, for good measure,
`pch_vector <- c(0,6,12,18,1, 8, 19, 15, 17)`.

Next, create the new settings:

```
 my_settings <- list(superpose.symbol=list(alpha = rep(1, 9), col=myColors,
    cex=rep(0.8, 9), fill= myColors, font = rep(1, 9), pch=pch_vector)
```

Then you can change the settings globally by using:

```
trellis.par.set(my_settings)
```

or locally, by using the `par.settings=` argument within your `featurePlot()` call:

```
    obj<-featurePlot(x=otto.all[,1:5], y = otto.all$target, plot="pairs", 
auto.key = list(columns = 9), par.settings=my_settings)
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `featurePlot` uses `lattice` to create the plot. Try to add `,col=c("blue","green",...)` as an argument and add the 9 colours that you want. 
You can also use [hex colour codes](http://www.color-hex.com/). For instance:

`,col=c("#d82b25","#073ca5","#9c9ea0","#ffce49","#03f92c","#16f4c2","#69167e","#191a92","#000000")`

Comment: See my update please. Your suggestion definitely affected plots, but not the legend.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

If you use a theme then `auto.key` is affected. For example you should see a difference in:

```
featurePlot(iris[, 1:4], iris$Species, plot="pairs", 
            auto.key = list(columns = 2))
```

and

```
col.whitebg()
featurePlot(iris[, 1:4], iris$Species, plot="pairs", 
            auto.key = list(columns = 2))
```